# Altering the initial value in Request scoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

In `PhaseListener` am calling `initialize` method.

```
public class myBean implements Serializable
{
 private boolean myBoolean = "true";

 public void initialize()
  {
    if(someCondition)
        {
            this.setMyBoolean(true);
         }
     else
       {
          this.setMyBoolean(false);  // Lets assume myBoolean gets set to false here
       }
  }
}
```

After this method executes, `index.jsf` is rendered to User.

In `index.xhtml` page, below code is there..

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.secondMethod}" value="someLink">
 </h:commandLink>

public String secondMethod()
{
  log.debug("Value of myBoolean variable is: " +this.isMyBoolean());
  return null;  
}
```

When User clicks on `someLink`, above code will print `myBoolean` as `true` instead of `false`.

`myBean` is in `request` scope. Since, its a new request, am forced to believe `myBoolean` is freshly assigned `true` value.

How can I overcome this? I mean, when `secondMethod` is called, if `myBoolean` was `false`, then it should be `false` in `secondMethod` also. And why is that `myBoolean` always remains `true`?

Comment: Perhaps someCondition is true for the postback?

Comment: No if it is `false` it will always be `false` and if it is `true` it will always be `true`

Comment: I think you should simply do some debugging. Set a breakpoint in the initialize method and check if it is called for the postback and if it changes the boolean. If there is no other place where you change the boolean, it MUST be called by the initialize method.

Comment: I did the required debugging. `initialize()` method is not getting called for the postback and it is not changing the boolean variable's value. When am clicking on `someLink` its only calling `secondMethod()` which is no where setting value for boolean variable.

Comment: @chkal I have put forth answer below. May be you can answer for Point no. 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. There are 2 parts in my question.

`1.` How can I overcome this?

`2.` why is that `myBoolean` always remains true?

Answer below is for point `1.`

```
<h:commandLink action="#{myBean.secondMethod}" value="someLink">
  <f:param name="newValue" value="#{myBean.myBoolean}"></f:param> // Use f:param to send the actual value   
 </h:commandLink>


public String secondMethod()
{
  String newValueIs = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("newValue");
  log.debug("Value of myBoolean variable is: " +newValueIs); //Prints false if it was false and true if it was true
  return null;  
}
```

However, am still not getting answer for `2.` point in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your initialize method is being called? How about putting an *@PostConstruct* annotation to initialization method to ensure that it will be called after the bean generated?